# How can I dynamically generate keys for my Form Group?

Tags: angular, for-loop, dynamic, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormGroup that I have declared in my component. It looks something like this.

```
this.providerForm = this.fb.group({
        specialty: this.entityService.getUrlQuery('specialty') || null,
        language: this.entityService.getUrlQuery('language') || null,
        gender: this.entityService.getUrlQuery('gender') || null,
        distance: this.entityService.getUrlQuery('distance') || null,
        affiliation: this.entityService.getUrlQuery('affiliation') || null,
        primaryCare: this.entityService.getUrlQuery('primaryCare') || '',
        accomodations: this.entityService.getUrlQuery('accomodations') || '',
        newPatients: this.entityService.getUrlQuery('newPatients') || ''
    });
```

I'm trying to make my form dynamic by using the key value in my array to set the key values of my Form Group. All of the values will call the same function and will pass the value of the key as a parameter. How can I populate my Form Group with the keys from my array?

Below is the relevant piece of my code.

```
this.pageConfigsService.getPageConfigs('provider_search', 'results')
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            if (this.entityService.getUrlQuery('entity_type') === 'provider') {
                this.pageConfigs = response['results']['provider'];

                for (let config of this.pageConfigs) {
                    this.providerForm = this.fb.group({
                        [config.key]: this.entityService.getUrlQuery([config.key]) || null
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    )

     // db.json
       "pharmacy": {
            "filters": [                    
                {
                    "key": "language",
                    "label": "Language",
                    "options": [
                        "English", "Spanish", "French"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "gender",
                    "label": "Gender",
                    "options": [
                        "Male", "Female"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "distance",
                    "label": "Distance",
                    "options": [
                        "under 5 miles", "under 10 miles", "under 15 miles", "under 25 miles", "under 50 miles", "far"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key": "affiliation",
                    "label": "Affiliation",
                    "options": [
                        "option 1", "option 2", "option 3"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for.

```
    this.filtersForm = new FormGroup({});
    this.pageConfigsService.getPageConfigs('provider_search', 'results')
    .subscribe(
        response => {
            this.pageConfigs = response['results'];
            this.filters = this.pageConfigs[this.entityService.getUrlQuery('entity_type')].filters;

            this.filters.forEach(filter => {
                console.log(filter.key);
                this.filtersForm.addControl(filter.key, new FormControl());
            });
        }
    )
```

At a basic level the formGroup({}) is compromised of key and value pairs that are made using the key and passing FormControl() as the value.